# C# FileStream IO Exception occurs in Web Service

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, io, iis-7.5

I face a problem in appending bytes to a file using filestream.I have a client application which splits the file bytes and send it to webservice in n-number of times instead of single send.

**my webservice code as follows**.

```
 public bool TransferFile(byte[] bytes, ref string token, ref string path, string extension)
    {
        string folderPath = string.Empty;
        if (System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DepositPath"] != null)
        {
            folderPath = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DepositPath"].ToString();
        }
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(token))
        {
            token = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();            
        }
        path = Path.Combine(folderPath, token + extension);

        if (!File.Exists(path))
        {
            using (FileStream fs = File.Create(path)){
                fs.Dispose();
            }
        }
        using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Write))
        {
            stream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            stream.Flush();
            stream.Close();
            stream.Dispose();
        }
        return true;
    }
```

I have open the file in append mode and append the bytes and close the stream.
even though i got IOException which says files is being used by some other process.
I have configure the application-pool-identities too.provide me some idea to fix this issue.

> **System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to process request. ---> System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file 'D:\Development Projects\IAM\FileTransporter\DepositFolder\79ede99d-d76a-4050-959d-17bb87fa6fdb.exe' because it is being used by another process.**
>      at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
>      at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy)
>      at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share)
>      at FileTransporterService.Service.TransferFile(Byte[] bytes, String& token, String& path, String extension) in D:\Development Projects\IAM\FileTransporter\FileTransporterService\Service.asmx.cs:line 36
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

Answer (score 0):

after if condition  gc.collect() will realese resource of that file

```
if (!File.Exists(path))
{
    using (FileStream fs = File.Create(path)){
          fs.Dispose();
    }
}
gc.collect()
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suspect that there's a problem with the first using statement that creates the file when it doesn't exist.  This file might not be flushed and closed by the operating system by the time you try and reopen the file with the second using statement.

There really is no reason to do this anyways, you can just create the FileStream with the FileMode.OpenOrCreate option, which accomplishes the same thing you were trying to do with opening the file twice.  Also, there's no reason to explicitly call Dispose() on the stream.  The purpose of the using statement if for Dispose to be called for you.

Try this:

```
    public bool TransferFile(byte[] bytes, ref string token, ref string path, string extension)
    {
        string folderPath = string.Empty;
        if (System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DepositPath"] != null)
        {
            folderPath = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DepositPath"].ToString();
        }
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(token))
        {
            token = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        }
        path = Path.Combine(folderPath, token + extension);

        using (var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Write))
        {
            stream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            stream.Flush();
            stream.Close();
        }
        return true;
    }
```